# What are the supported character entities for XML comments?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-comments

In the following example, **`&amp;`** and **`&#916;`** are OK but **`&Delta;`** is not (the latter two are both Δ). The compiler issues a warning similar to:

```
warning CS1570: XML comment on 'XXX.DocumentedMethod()' has badly formed XML -- 'Reference to undefined entity 'Delta'.'
```

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  &amp; &Delta; &#916;
    /// </summary>
    public void DocumentedMethod()
    {

    }
```

**What are the supported character entities for XML comments?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a matter of comments, it's XML itself. XML only inherently knows about `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;` and `&quot;` as well as the numeric entities. Anything else has to be declared explicitly.

See [section 4.6 of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-predefined-ent) for further information.

Comment: Thanks! I am honored that Jon Skeet answered my question =)